# How to break up Qt code into separate parts?

Tags: c++, qt

So I am currently writing a Qt app, but am fairly new to it and am unsure of how certain things should be designed. As I add more and more code, my `MainWindow.cpp` is getting large and unruly. I am curious of what is the proper way to separate my code up in to smaller files. Each of the components that I wish to move to a separate file is making changes to the UI. What I am currently doing is literally just creating a new .cpp file, and then including my MainWindow and also the MainWindow ui. Here is an example of a function that I placed in its own file.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QPalette>
#include "master_main_window.h"
#include "ui_master_main_window.h"
#include "cmd_net.h"
#include "cmd.h"


/*
 * Send a command/data packet to the host
 */
void MasterMainWindow::sendCommand() {

    // Disable some GUI components
    ui->con_btn_cmd_disc->setEnabled(false);
    ui->con_btn_cmd_rec->setEnabled(false);
    ui->cmd_edit->setEnabled(false);
    ui->cmd_btn_send->setEnabled(false);

    // Send the packet through the open socket
    sendCmdPacket(ui->cmd_edit->text().toLocal8Bit().data(), cmdSocket);

    // Enable the socket notifier
    cmdSockNotifier->setEnabled(true);

    qDebug() << "Command sent:"
             << (ui->cmd_edit->text().toLocal8Bit().data())
             << "\nSent Packet";
}
```

As you can see, I have simply included the "master_main_window.h" and "ui_master_main_window.h" which gives me access to all of the different functions/variables/ui available in the MainWindow class. **I am curious if I am doing this the proper way, or if there is a better method to achieve my goal of separating the functions into separate files.**

Answer (score 2):

If I'm getting what you're asking correctly, since you're working with pointers here you can simply write other classes in different files and pass your variables in `ui` to them.
For example, let's say you're `ui` has these variables in it:

```
QWidget * leftWidget;
QWidget * centerWidget;
QWidget * rightWidget;
```

You can write classes who inherit `QWidget` and give these variables to them, like this:

```
class leftWidgetClass : public QWidget
{
  //your code here
}
```

and so on...
And then in the constructor of your `MainWindow` you can do this:

```
leftWidget = new leftWidgetClass();
rightWidget = new rightWidgetClass();
centerWidget = new centerWidgetClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to not using `ui` namespace and `mainwindow` methods outside of `mainwindow` class. You should sublass `QWidget` or any other classes, which functionality you want to extend, create all the functionality you need (like `doImportantStuff()`) and include this new class header ( let's call it `myWidget`) in `mainwindow.h`. Then you can create those `myWidget`'s in mainwindow, add them to `ui` (ether through disigner, add QWidget, click promote to , select your class, or by adding to layout manually) and use all of their signals and functionality, that you've created, like:

```
connect(ui->doWorkButtot(),SIGNAL(clicked()), myWidget, SLOT(doImportantStuff()));`
```

again, changes to `ui` you can do via `signals and slots mechanism`; In `myWidget` when you feel, you have to change ui somehow, `emit` a signal and catch it in `mainwindow` with `connect`. Example:

```
myWidget.h:

...
signals:
void needUiChange();
....
public slots:
myWidget::doImportantStuff(){

....

emit needUiChange();
//  you can emit signals with params also:
//  emit setToolTipText(QString("from signal));
...
```

and in mainwindow catch signal with connect:

```
connect(myWidget, SIGNAL(needUiChange(),this,SLOT(updateUI());
// actually you can connect directly to let's say `pushButton`'s slot `hide()`
```